# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I have just launched my First Android Application on the Play Store name  **Indian Logo Quiz**

And I am receiving certain crash reports. Of which one is This :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.indian.logoquiz/com.indian.logoquiz.Play}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class     <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at              com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:    56)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:666)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:467)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:327)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1928)
at com.indian.logoquiz.Play.onCreate(Play.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:596)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:817)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2854)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3460)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:446)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
... 26 more
```

My **play.xml** is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/playpage">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lvl1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:text="" 

        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lvl2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:text=""
        />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lvl3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.34"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.33"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lvl4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lvl5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lvl6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.34"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.33" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lvl7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lvl8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/lvl9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.34"
        android:alpha="0.85"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The app is getting crashed on pressing level 1 button .... 
Can it be because of nested weight in any case ?? 
Please help !....

Answer (score 0):

You are getting Out of Memory Exception for Images in your Activity.

When any device with small heap or buffer size uses application it may get Memory exception because you may have used High resolution images.

try below code to reduce memory usage of application bitmaps.

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    Bitmap b = null;

        //Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
    fis.close();

    int scale = 1;
    if (o.outHeight > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE || o.outWidth > IMAGE_MAX_SIZE) {
        scale = (int)Math.pow(2, (int) Math.round(Math.log(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE / 
           (double) Math.max(o.outHeight, o.outWidth)) / Math.log(0.5)));
    }

    //Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    fis = new FileInputStream(f);
    b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o2);
    fis.close();

    return b;
}
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: I'm using the code:
    public Bitmap getBitmap(Context ctx, String pathNameRelativeToAssetsFolder) 
 {
  InputStream bitmapIs = null;
  Bitmap bmp = null;
  try 
  {
   bitmapIs = ctx.getAssets().open(pathNameRelativeToAssetsFolder);
      bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmapIs);
      
  } 
  catch (IOException e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally 
  {
      if(bitmapIs != null) 
      {
       try 
       {
     bitmapIs.close();
     
    } 
       catch (IOException e) 
    {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
      }
  }
  return bmp;
 }

Comment: As I have saved all images in my assets folder!

Comment: but as far as logcat is concern there is only memory exception in bitmap. so it would be better to check in which condition it gets error?

Comment: don't save all your images in asset folder. instead save it in SDcard so that your app doesn't get heavy. i can say from your app name that it will be using lot of images. so try using SDcard.

Comment: Could you guide me to do so ?

Comment: You need server for that. store all your images in one folder in server and on application load try to get images from server and save it to sd card. you can see this example in talking tom app. where images and other resources are downloaded from server after app is installed.

Comment: still i want to know when this error exactly happens?? means everytime you load or on certain event it happens??

Comment: Whenever i click a button, around 30 images should load ! .. But the application Force closes ..

Comment: If possible hava a look at my Android Application : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.indian.logoquiz

Comment: 30 images loads from where??

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have talked about `Out of Memory Exception`, but since you've talked about nested weight's here is something which might help in understanding that better. It might not solve your problem but clear few things.

In general there are two parameters which are used together many a times:
`android:weightSum="1"` and `android:layout_weight`. If you don't specify the weightSum in the outer layout, its considered to be `1`. The sum of all `android:layout_weight` inside an outerlayout should be equal to the weight sum of that outer layout. Eg:
If you have 3 Buttons inside a `LinearLayout` and you want to define equal weights to them, then you can do it as follows.

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:weightSum="3"
     >

    <Button
       ...
       android:layout_weight="1"
     />

    <Button
       ...
       android:layout_weight="1"
     />

    <Button
       ...
       android:layout_weight="1"
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Similarly you can do for layouts:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="3"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        ...
         android:layout_weight="1"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        ...
         android:layout_weight="1"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        ...
         android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put end tag for parent Layout in last. `</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to remove Bitmaps from memory as soon as you do not need them.
A way you can do it by recycling the Bitmap:

```
Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(wid, hgt, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
 // Use here your newImage...
 newImage.recycle();
 newImage = null;
```

Comment: you should not recycle image before using it. When you are confirmed that no more reference of the image will be used in future only then you should recycle it. otherwise u will get NullpointerException. Anyway can you post your codes where u are recycling?